# Get File Version of .exe in java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, docker

Question - Get File Version of .exe in java on Linux for some strange client.

Solution -

I used JNA library to read file version using Java. Given below code is running fine on windows platform but it is throwing below error on Linux docker image.

"Unable to load library 'version': Error loading shared library libversion.so: No such file or directory Error loading shared library libversion.so: No such file or directory Native library (linux-x86-64/libversion.so) not found in resource path..".

```
private String GetFileVersion(String filePath) {

    File fileToCheck = new File(filePath);
    short[] rtnData = new short[4];


    int infoSize = Version.INSTANCE.GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileToCheck.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    Pointer buffer = Kernel32.INSTANCE.LocalAlloc(WinBase.LMEM_ZEROINIT, infoSize);

    try {

        Version.INSTANCE.GetFileVersionInfo(fileToCheck.getAbsolutePath(), 0, infoSize, buffer);
        IntByReference outputSize = new IntByReference();
        PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
        Version.INSTANCE.VerQueryValue(buffer, "\\", pointer, outputSize);
        VerRsrc.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO fileInfoStructure = new VerRsrc.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO(pointer.getValue());

        rtnData[0] = (short) (fileInfoStructure.dwFileVersionMS.longValue() >> 16);
        rtnData[1] = (short) (fileInfoStructure.dwFileVersionMS.longValue() & 0xffff);
        rtnData[2] = (short) (fileInfoStructure.dwFileVersionLS.longValue() >> 16);
        rtnData[3] = (short) (fileInfoStructure.dwFileVersionLS.longValue() & 0xffff);

        return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s", rtnData[0], rtnData[1], rtnData[2], rtnData[3]);

    } catch (Exception exception) {

        return null;

    } finally {
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.GlobalFree(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: "...No such file or directory ..." Indicates to me either the path to the file is incorrect or the target file does not exist inside the container. Going from Win to *nix file paths can be a pain. Double check the location of resources.

Comment: Hey @DavidJEddy, I am not a Java/linux expert. Can you please help me in troubleshooting this? This "Version" class is from JNA library and I have no control over this.

Comment: Sadly I am not familiar with JNA. Though the issue you seem to be having is one of file path / file existing. The application is looking for a file and it does not exists at the given location.

Comment: @DavidJEddy, Can you please remove the down-vote? I posted the question after spending couple of hours on it.

Comment: What research did you do on the problem? Do you have a version of your native code compiled for Linux? Is it installed on your Linux machine? What is the use case for looking up `exe` files on a Linux machine? What program is this a part of? Your question is missing a lot of information.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried to install JNA on Linux machine through docker file but it did not work. I researched if I can retrieve the version of .exe in Java without using JNA.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by answering the question that you asked, though I doubt it is what you actually need to know.

The types of different executable file formats are encoded in the first few bytes of the file.   For example, ELF files (executables, shared libraries) are described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) Wikipedia page.

So there are a number of ways to find out what kind of executable in Java:

1. Write some code that reads the first few bytes and decodes the file header information, as per the format described in the Wikipedia link above.
2. Find an existing Java library that does this and work out how to do this.  (Google for "java file magic library" and see what you can find.)
3. Read about the Linux `file` command and write some Java code to run `file` on each library and parse the output.

---

What I think you *actually* need to do is a bit different:

1. Locate the file or files in the file system that the Java is looking for: apparently `libversion.so` or `linux-x86-64/libversion.so`.  (The file could well be a symlink.  Follow it.)
2. Run `file` on each file to check that it is the right kind of library.  They need to be 32 or 64 bit *corresponding the JVM you are running*, and the correct ABI and ISA for the platform.
3. Check that the files are where the JVM expects to find them.  The JVM searches for libraries in directories listed in the "java.library.path" system property.  You can (if necessary) set the path using a `-Djava.library.path=...` JVM option.

See ["java.library.path – What is it and how to use"](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/) for more information on library loading.

(There is absolutely no need to do step 2 "from" or "in" Java.)

Comment: Hi, Thank for your time. I need to access the .exe's file version not the content type. I am exploring 1st and 3rd steps in 2nd section if these fixes can help me in running the JNA on Linux. This exception is coming for "Version" class which is part of JNA library. Kindly let me know if you have know some alternate approach.

Comment: What do you mean by file version?  Do you mean the version *number*?   Like libvorbis.so.0 -> libvorbis.so.0.4.8 ?  AFAIK that is only available via the file and symlink names.

Comment: Yes, I need to read the version number. Please suggest me if you have some alternative/better approach.

Comment: Easy: you just need to use the `java.nio.Files::readSymbolicLink` method to see what the symlinks point at.  Or use the `file` and/or `ls` commands from the command line.

Comment: Will `java.nio.Files::readSymbolicLink` fix the issue in my current approach? or you are proposing it to read version number? I am sorry for being irritating but I am very new to this platform.

Comment: I don't know what the issue in your current approach is.  You haven't explained properly what your approach is.  You haven't even clearly explained what problem you are trying to solve.   Are you trying to figure out why you are getting the exceptions?  Or are you trying to write some code in Java to do something?  And if so, what?

Comment: It all stems from this confusing statement of yours:  *"I researched if I can retrieve the version of .exe in Java without using JNA."*  - You seem to be trying to retrieve the version of something *using* a Java program.  But in Linux there is no such thing as a ".exe".  There are executable programs, and there are native libraries, and they are not the same thing.   If you want people to help you you need to explain yourself **clearly** and use terminology that actually makes sense.

Comment: One final note: if you are tying to use the "libversion" from here: https://github.com/repology/libversion, this is  NOT a library for finding versions.  It is a library for doing version matching using structured version numbers.   For example, when satisfying version constraints.  You have to have gotten hold of the version strings *from somewhere* before you start.  This doesn't match what you seem to be asking in your question.

Comment: I am downloading the .exe from some external source and then trying to read the version number. I used JNA to do this and it is working well on my windows machine but it throws given error on Linux. I am working in direction to fix this exception. I have no information where this `libversion.so` is located. This error is coming from JNA package's `Version` class.

Comment: That doesn't make sense JNA doesn't have a Version class.  It is an interface.  Furthermore the JNA project (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) does not define or use anything called "libversion".  (Search the source tree yourself!)  So the error is not coming from JNA's Version "class".   Perhaps you should show us the code that runs on Windows ... in a form that we can examine and build for ourselves.

Comment: You may need to download the libversion source code and build and install it on your Linux machine.  I can't identify any Linux packages that include it.   But I'm not convinced this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated the question with source code.

Comment: Downloading that libversion won't help.  It is the wrong one, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally worked out what you are doing.

The `Version` you are using is actually coming from the package `com.sun.jna.platform.win32`.   It is not part of the JNA library (jna.jar).  I think it is actually part of jna-platform.jar.  If I understand things correctly, that is the generated JNA adapter library for the Windows COM dlls.

If I have that correct, you would actually need the Windows COM native libraries compiled and built for the Linux platform to do what you are trying to do.

AFAIK, that's not possible.

So how could you make this work?  Basically you need to do one of the following:

- Look for an existing *pure Java* library for extracting the version information from a Windows ".exe" file.  I don't think it is likely that you will find one.
- Find the specification for the Windows ".exe" file format and write your own Java code to extract the version information.  I haven't looked for the spec to see how much work it would be.

Then you *rewrite* the code that you added your question to use the alternative API.

---

The "libversion" file that I mentioned in my other answer is not relevant.  It is something else.  It is a red herring.

Comment: I agree with you and the given code would never work on Linux. The `File` package on linux does not give `FileVersion` .I am trying to use `exiftool` package on Linux to read `FileVersion` but it's dependencies are giving me headache.